# Android Design Support Library

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design

I have found [this](http://hmkcode.com/material-design-app-android-design-support-library-appcompat/) after a google search about the android design support library.

It states: "Android Design Support Library brings a number of material design components that are compatiable [sic] with all Android 2.1 or higher devices."

I am wondering if this means that the android design support library should only be used with pre-lollipop devices or if it is the same thing as using material design in api-21 now.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Design Support Library only provides some components introduced by Material Design.

To use the Material Design theme, you have to use AppCompat Support Library (or set your `minSdkVersion` to `21` or higher).

So even if you are developing for API 21+, you still won't have access to those components (Floating Action Button, Snackbar, NavigationView, ...), as they are not included in Android.

You can get more information about the Design Support Library in the [official announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).